How to create advanced slider controller (like Maya's)?

I've noticed that there are some rigging features in Maya. One of these it's "slider controller" that can go through the body and influence on it. So how I can create similar controller in Blender ?
There is a screen recording about how it works 

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

You should be able to do this using Bone constraints.
The slider controller in that case would probably be a target bone or an empty. The Bone constraints only show up in pose mode of the rig and you can apply them to singular bones.
Maybe damped track or inverse kinematic would do what you intend.
If I'm looking at your example maybe a spline rigging setup like for a tentacle could also be what you are looking for, as there are similarities in how the spine is controlled on the bear to how the curve on a tentacle would be controlled.
This is a pretty in depth tutorial on rigging tweaker bones on an IK chain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBXFJA6UdaI

Thank you for your attention! This author's rig allows to rich flexibility, but it still not be able to control, influence a big amount of bones with one controller. In my case I need a little bit different mechanism. Bear's rig has already existed and I need to somehow add constraints that could influence on the def bones when "a slider control" right on them.
